# Reference error Angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular, and I am stuck in first chapter :-(

I am using angular 2.0, but when i try to create a module I get error "angular is not defined".

My plunker:  [Plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/btad9tLLmkdnAZegpKwW?p=preview)

my script:

```
(function() {

  console.log("Hello");
  var app = angular.Module("gitHubViewer", []);
  app.controller("MainController", MainController);

    var MainController = function($scope) {
      $scope.message = "Hello World!";
    };


  }());
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="gitHubViewer">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular.js" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.20" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Can some body please help, is this a wrong way of creating module?

Thanks

Comment: Your reference library https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular.js is not working, Code is fine!

Comment: This looks more like an Angular 1 setup rather than Angular 2. Take a look here: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html. Also the like to the angular 2 library 404s, I think it should be https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular2.js

Comment: i tried adding angular version 1.4 but still the same problem. Please see the updated plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular.js link.

Display `404 Not Found`.

Please download angularJS From https://angularjs.org/ and  add it in your project.

Comment: I get the same result when i user 1.4.0 rci version. Please see this updated plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/btad9tLLmkdnAZegpKwW?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, in your code some mistake, please see this link (http://plnkr.co/edit/e3w54TZEmfj8h5O6BX7B?p=preview).

Add ng-app='gitHubViewer' attribute in html tag.

Use angular.module instead of angular.Module

Answer (score 0):

I've not looked into Angular 2 very much but your code looks more like Angular 1 to me.

Angular 2 apps are bootstrapped in a very different way using ES6 components (specifically `System`). It should look more like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular 2 Hello World!</title>
    <script src="/dist/es6-shim.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <my-app></my-app>
    <script>
    // Rewrite the paths to load the files
    System.paths = {
        'angular2/*': '/angular2/*.js', // Angular
        'rtts_assert/*': '/rtts_assert/*.js', // Runtime assertions
        'app': 'app.es6' // The my-app component
    };

    // Kick off the application
    System.import('app');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This code was taken from this excellent tutorial: [Getting Started with Angular 2.0](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-angular-2-0/).